# How to add a boolean flag to a variable based on a condition in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a PS script retrieving all the devices from AD with their OU information like below:

```
$UserList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName,LastLogonDate 

$Results = foreach ($UL_Item in $UserList)
    {
        [array]$OuList = @($UL_Item.DistinguishedName.Split(',')).
            Where({$_ -match 'OU='}).
            ForEach({$_.Split('=')[-1]}).
            Trim()

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $UL_Item.Name
            OU_1 = $OuList[0]
            OU_2 = $OuList[1]
            OU_3 = $OuList[2]
            OU_4 = $OuList[3]
            OU_5 = $OuList[4]
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to add a flag called `IsServer` to my variable: `$Results` and set it to True if any of the OU is equal to "Domain Servers", so I am looking for the correct syntax for something like:

```
...
OU_5 = $OuList[4]
IsServer = if ($OuList[0]="Domain Servers" OR 
               $OuList[1]="Domain Servers" OR 
               $OuList[2]="Domain Servers" OR 
               $OuList[3]="Domain Servers" OR 
               $OuList[4]="Domain Servers" OR ) then true else false end
```

What is the best way to manage this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if($OuList -contains "Domain Servers")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
IsServer = @{$true="true";$false="false"}[($OuList -contains "Domain Servers"]
```